# Spring JPA without hibernate

Tags: spring, jpa, annotations

I am not able to understand the below method in Spring -JPA.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, BigInteger>{
    public List<Vehicle> findAll(Sort sort);

}
```

Vehice is a entity or domainobject.

What does the method findAll(Sort sort)  do.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This declare the method already in `JpaRepository` again.

```
List<T> JpaRepository.findAll(Sort sort);
```

with `T = Vehicle` take all vehicles form the database (or NOSQL store) with a the given sorting and returns them.

@RepositoryRestResource is a annotation to publish this as an HATEAOS rest resource.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to find all vehicles, sorted as specified by the `Sort` parameter.